Xcode 16 Crashing When Adding Objects or Constraints in XIB Files
I’m experiencing frequent crashes in both Xcode 16 and Xcode 16.1 Beta when adding an object or a constraint in XIB files. This also happens with XIB files I created in Xcode 16. The crashes make it impossible to work on my project. Has anyone else encountered this issue? What can I do to resolve it?
I was wondering what kind of weirdness I would encounter with the new Xcode, but I didn't expect a problem of this level. Apple has surprised me once again.
Xcode crash log:

Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
  11  start + 2840 (dyld + 25204) [0x191f58274]
  11  NSApplicationMain + 888 (AppKit + 17484) [0x195ecd44c]
  11  -[IDEApplication run] + 60 (IDEKit + 200416) [0x1077a4ee0]
  11  -[NSApplication run] + 520 (AppKit + 187300) [0x195ef6ba4]
  11  -[NSApplication _handleEvent:] + 60 (AppKit + 5712260) [0x19643b984]
  11  -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] + 236 (IDEKit + 200880) [0x1077a50b0]
  11  -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 1656 (AppKit + 9827740) [0x19682859c]
  11  -[IDESearchPanel sendEvent:] + 308 (IDEKit + 3529164) [0x107ad19cc]
  11  -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 284 (AppKit + 1449204) [0x19602acf4]
  11  -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 284 (AppKit + 1449952) [0x19602afe0]
  11  -[NSWindow _handleMouseDraggedEvent:] + 52 (AppKit + 11431568) [0x1969afe90]
  11  forwardMethod + 252 (AppKit + 1903444) [0x196099b54]
  11  forwardMethod + 252 (AppKit + 1903444) [0x196099b54]
  11  forwardMethod + 252 (AppKit + 1903444) [0x196099b54]
  11  @objc LibraryTileView.LibraryCollectionView.mouseDragged(with:) + 52 (DVTLibraryKit + 61136) [0x1065d2ed0]
  11  LibraryTileView.LibraryCollectionView.mouseDragged(with:) + 1588 (DVTLibraryKit + 60704) [0x1065d2d20]
  11  -[DVTLibraryController libraryTileView:dragItems:primaryItem:withMouseDownEvent:andMouseDraggedEvent:] + 212 (DVTLibraryKit + 26664) [0x1065ca828]
  11  -[DVTLibraryController dragFromView:withTargetFrame:dragItems:primaryItem:withMouseDownEvent:andMouseDraggedEvent:] + 248 (DVTLibraryKit + 26980) [0x1065ca964]
  11  -[DVTLibraryController dragAssets:withMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:initialDraggedImageState:allowedOperations:imageLocationInWindow:] + 204 (DVTLibraryKit + 23400) [0x1065c9b68]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryController populatePasteboard:withAssets:defaultDraggedImageState:identifierMapTable:] + 132 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2188536) [0x1387664f8]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryController populatePasteboard:withAssets:identifierMapTable:] + 260 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2186312) [0x138765c48]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryController prepareDocumentlessMetadataDuring:] + 132 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2186032) [0x138765b30]
  11  +[IBDocument recordDocumentlessMetadataWithContainer:during:] + 128 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 992600) [0x138642558]
  11  __78-[IBObjectLibraryController populatePasteboard:withAssets:identifierMapTable:]_block_invoke + 144 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2186616) [0x138765d78]
  11  IBSetFallbackDocumentForEffectiveDeviceTypeDescriptionDuring + 108 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2349544) [0x13878d9e8]
  11  __78-[IBObjectLibraryController populatePasteboard:withAssets:identifierMapTable:]_block_invoke_2 + 216 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2186880) [0x138765e80]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryAsset objectContainer] + 24 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2175296) [0x138763140]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryAsset pasteboardObjects] + 72 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2175192) [0x1387630d8]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryAssetProvider pasteboardObjectsForAsset:] + 32 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2178632) [0x138763e48]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryAsset effectiveRepresentedObject] + 20 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2174280) [0x138762d48]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryAsset createContentIfNeeded] + 268 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2173540) [0x138762a64]
  11  -[IBObjectLibraryAsset instantiateObjectForRole:] + 272 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2173184) [0x138762900]
  11  +[IBUIView(IBUIViewIntegration) ibDidInstantiateObject:forAsset:role:] + 188 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 1593056) [0x1373dcee0]
  11  +[IBUIView(IBUIViewIntegration) ibDidInstantiateView:forAsset:role:] + 220 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 1593480) [0x1373dd088]
  11  -[IBUIView(IBUIViewIntegration) ibSuggestLayoutAllowingResizingTopLevelView:] + 72 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 1602604) [0x1373df42c]
  11  -[IBUIView ibAllowDirectIntrisicContentSizeQueryOnCacheMissDuring:] + 68 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 1451012) [0x1373ba404]
  11  __77-[IBUIView(IBUIViewIntegration) ibSuggestLayoutAllowingResizingTopLevelView:]_block_invoke + 48 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 1602664) [0x1373df468]
  11  -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibSuggestLayoutAllowingResizingTopLevelView:] + 24 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 3165320) [0x138854c88]
  11  -[IBUIView(IBUIViewIntegration) ibPreferredSize] + 120 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 1616592) [0x1373e2ad0]
  11  -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibIntrinsicContentFrameSize] + 32 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 3165412) [0x138854ce4]
  11  -[IBUIView intrinsicContentSize] + 232 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 1451604) [0x1373ba654]
  11  +[IBObjectValueMarshaller valueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:targetRuntime:deviceTypeDescription:defaultValue:diagnosticsBlock:] + 284 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 229248) [0x13728ff80]
  11  +[IBObjectValueMarshaller valuesForKeyPaths:ofObject:context:targetRuntime:deviceTypeDescription:defaultValues:diagnosticsBlock:] + 976 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 227032) [0x13728f6d8]
  11  +[IBPlatformToolFailureHandler performRequestWithTool:failureHandlerBlock:failureMessageBlock:diagnosticsConfigurationBlock:duringBlock:] + 124 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 2334016) [0x138789d40]
  11  __129+[IBObjectValueMarshaller valuesForKeyPaths:ofObject:context:targetRuntime:deviceTypeDescription:defaultValues:diagnosticsBlock:]_block_invoke.133 + 68 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 228908) [0x13728fe2c]
  11  -[IBCocoaTouchToolProxy valuesForKeyPaths:ofMarshalledObjectRequest:] + 144 (IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration + 185332) [0x1372853f4]
  11  -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] + 196 (IDEInterfaceBuilderKit + 175936) [0x13857af40]
  11  DVTDispatchSync + 148 (DVTFoundation + 1158196) [0x102bbac34]
  11  _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 148 (libdispatch.dylib + 80752) [0x192137b70]
  11  __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 340 (libdispatch.dylib + 81832) [0x192137fa8]
  11  _dispatch_event_loop_wait_for_ownership + 436 (libdispatch.dylib + 163760) [0x19214bfb0]
  11  kevent_id + 8 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 11016) [0x19229bb08]
 *11  ??? (kernel.release.t6020 + 5639504) [0xfffffe0008c64d50]


I tried to add a button, label to the view in a XIB file, and Xcode crashed. The same thing happens when I try to add a constraint.

Have you checked their bug tracker? Can you provide steps to reproduce this?

@UlrichEckhardt I couldn't find similar issue. Strangely, it’s working now. I had turned off and restarted the macOS, but it didn’t fix it. I also tried commands like “delete all Xcode-related settings,” which were recommended, but they didn’t work either. However, after restarting the computer, it got fixed. I had turned it off and on before, but maybe I’m misremembering the order. Perhaps I ran this command after power on/off, and that’s why it worked. Or maybe the issue resolved directly after the restart.

Strangely, it’s working now.
I had turned off and restarted the computer, but it didn’t fix it.
I also tried this command for erasing all Xcode related settings
“delete all Xcode-related settings”

but they didn’t work either. However, after restarting the computer, it got fixed.
I had turned it off and on before, but maybe I’m misremembering the order. Perhaps I ran this command after power off/on, and that’s why it worked.  Or maybe the issue resolved directly after the restart.
If issue reappears, I will update you here.
